# F# best way to swap letters in a string

Tags: string, replace, f#

Im currently trying to figure out the best way possible to take a string (fairly long string in my case) and replace all occurrences of let's say "A" with "B", and all occurrences of "B" with "A".

I've come up with two ways of doing it but there are probably a bette, faster and nicer way to implement this.

The first one is

```
    let stringFun letter1 letter2 = fun letter -> 
                                      match letter with
                                      | letter when letter = letter1 -> letter2
                                      | letter when letter = letter2 -> letter1
                                      | letter                       -> letter

    let replaceLetter letter1 letter2 text = String.map (stringFun letter1 letter2) text
```

With the second one being

```
    let remapInput (cipher: string) l1 l2 = cipher.Replace(l1, '&').Replace(l2, l1).Replace('&', l2)
```

This one of course only works when there are no '&' in the given string.

Comment: actually the first one is a pretty good way to do it, nice and simple.

Comment: @OSherlock, I noticed you accepted my answer but didn't upvote, if that means you still have questions, or needed something else, feel free to ask! It's an open forum here ;).

Comment: @Abel Im sorry, rarely use SO so i'm not really sure how everything works around here. Thank you for your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for and it was well explained so it was easy to understand, thanks! :)

Comment: @O.Sherlock, tx & glad to be of help, and SO is great, you should come here more often ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly a million ways to do what you want to do, and I'd assume at some point you may want more flexibility than just swapping two letters. The functionality that does this is called "string translation" in some programming languages, where a translation is done by "mapping" a search-list to a target-list for each character that you want modified.

Here's a generic way to do it and it is faster than your original approach (by about 3x):

```
/// Replaces each char in str that matches a char in search for the corresponding 
/// char in repl. Array of search and repl must be equal in size.
let translate search repl (str: string) =
    // you can just as well use String.map, but it's slower, see comments
    str.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.map (fun c ->
        match search |> Array.tryFindIndex ((=) c) with
        | Some i -> Array.item i repl
        | None -> c
    ) |> String
```

You call it like as follows (and you can use it with any number of characters to replace, not just swapping):

```
> translate [|'A';'B'|] [|'B';'A'|] "ABracadaBRA";;
val it : String = "BAracadaARB"
```

In terms of timings compared to your approach, there's a clear difference (also notice the much smaller GC pressure):

```
> for i=1 to 1_000_000 do translate [|'A';'B'|] [|'B';'A'|] "ABracadaBRA" |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:00.306, CPU: 00:00:00.312, GC gen0: 91, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

> for i=1 to 1_000_000 do replaceLetter 'A' 'B' "ABracadaBRA" |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.053, CPU: 00:00:01.076, GC gen0: 185, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

---

If the "generic" solution is a bit too much and you want raw speed plus simple code for just swapping the chars, this works just as well:

```
/// Swaps each search char for repl char in str in vice versa
let swap search repl (str: string) =
    str.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.map (fun c -> if c = search then repl elif c = repl then search else c)
    |> String
```

And it performs another 3.5x faster, beating the original by 10x and even less GC pressure ;)

```
> for i=1 to 1_000_000 do swap 'A' 'B' "ABracadaBRA" |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:00.101, CPU: 00:00:00.109, GC gen0: 23, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
```

---

EDIT: I didn't check your `remapInput` version for timings earlier (mainly because you cannot rely on the `&` for not being present), but it is pretty fast already, it clocks in at 00:00.183 on my machine, with same GC pressure as my last solution. It can do that by using a modifiable array internally. We can do that too with my first and second solution if you want even more raw speed at expense of more complex code.

If we take my last solution and use a mutable array internally, we can squeeze out even better performance and even less GC pressure yet:

```
/// Swaps each search char for repl char in str in vice versa
let fastSwap search repl (str: string) =
    let x = str.ToCharArray()
    let mutable i = -1
    for c in x do
        i <- i + 1
        if c = search then x.[i] <- repl
        elif c = repl then x.[i] <- search
    String x
```

Performance is pretty amazing:

```
> for i=1 to 1_000_000 do fastSwap 'A' 'B' "ABracadaBRA" |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:00.067, CPU: 00:00:00.062, GC gen0: 16, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Comment: Why do you call `ToCharArray()`? Couldn't you use `String.map` instead?

Comment: @HenrikHansen, I was experimenting with the `mutable` for speed-up and the original `String.map` appeared to be very slow so I didn't consider to investigate further. Let me compare it once more, sec.

Comment: @HenrikHansen, just timed it. Taken my first `translate` above, replace `ToCharArray` and the final cast for `String.map` and use the same timings, it clocks in at 380ms (vs 310ms now for the original). So yeah, the build-in version is slower. `String.map` also had about 12% higher GC pressure. But you are right, that should've been part of my answer. I've added it.

Comment: As you can see [here at String.map](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/a797a247fd20a535351ba7751f6405439be9cdfe/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/string.fs#L33) it uses a `StringBuilder`, which is usually quite fast, but apparently the extra allocations and array copying cause it to be slower than the approach above.